# How are nested checkpoints resolved in snakemake?

Tags: snakemake

I need to use nested checkpoints in snakemake since for every dynamic file I have to create again other dynamic files. So far, I am unable to resolve the two checkpoints properly. Below, you find a minimal toy example.

It seems that until the first checkout is not properly resolved, the second checkpoint is not even executed, thus a single aggregate rule won't work. 
I don't know how to invoke the two checkpoints and resolve the wildcards.

```py
import os.path
import glob
rule all: 
  input: 
    'collect/all_done.txt'


#generate a number of files
checkpoint create_files:
  output: 
    directory('files')
  run: 
    import random
    r = random.randint(1,10)
    for x in range(r):
      output_dir = output[0] + '/' + str(x+1) 
      import os
      if not os.path.isdir(output_dir):
        os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)
      output_file=output_dir + '/test.txt'
      print(output_file)
      with open(output_file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(x+1))

checkpoint create_other_files: 
  input: 'files/{i}/test.txt'
  output: directory('other_files/{i}/')
  shell: 
    '''
    L=$(( $RANDOM % 10))
    for j in $(seq 1 $L);
        do 
            mkdir -p {output}/{j}
            cp -f {input} {output}/$j/test2.txt
        done
    '''


def aggregate(wildcards):
  i_wildcard = checkpoints.create_files.get(**wildcards).output[0]
  print('in_def_aggregate')
  print(i_wildcard)
  j_wildcard = checkpoints.create_other_files.get(**wildcards).output[0]
  print(j_wildcard)
  split_files = expand('other_files/{i}/{j}/test2.txt', 
    i =glob_wildcards(os.path.join(i_wildcard, '{i}/test.txt')).i, 
    j = glob_wildcards(os.path.join(j_wildcard, '{j}/test2.txt')).j
  )
  return split_files

#non-sense collect function
rule collect:
  input: aggregate
  output: touch('collect/all_done.txt')
```

Currently, I get the following error from snakemake:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /bin/bash
Provided cores: 1
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       all
        1       collect
        1       create_files
        3

[Thu Nov 14 14:45:01 2019]
checkpoint create_files:
    output: files
    jobid: 2
Downstream jobs will be updated after completion.

Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       create_files
        1
files/1/test.txt
files/2/test.txt
files/3/test.txt
files/4/test.txt
files/5/test.txt
files/6/test.txt
files/7/test.txt
files/8/test.txt
files/9/test.txt
files/10/test.txt
Updating job 1.
in_def_aggregate
files
[Thu Nov 14 14:45:02 2019]
Error in rule create_files:
    jobid: 2
    output: files

InputFunctionException in line 53 of /TL/stat_learn/work/feldmann/Phd/Projects/HIVImmunoAdapt/HIVIA/playground/Snakefile2:
WorkflowError: Missing wildcard values for i
Wildcards:

Removing output files of failed job create_files since they might be corrupted:
files
Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

I am interested in having the files /other_files/{checkpoint_1_wildcard}/{checkpoint_2_wildcard}/test2.txt

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. `create_subdirectories` and `create_files` will give an IOError, and when I try to run this code it complains that `create_files` exits non-zero.

Comment: As stated above, I have two consequent jobs that produce dynamic output files, s.t. in the end the following files should be created  /{checkpoint_wildcard1}/{checkpoint_wildcard2}/file.txt. I was unable to provide the correct aggregate function to resolve the checkpoint wildcards. 

The code was just a toy example. I will fix the IOError, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you were trying to do, so I rewrote it quite some. But does clarify the problem?

```
import glob
import random
from pathlib import Path


rule all:
    input:
        'collect/all_done.txt'


checkpoint first:
    output:
        directory('first')
    run:
        for i in range(random.randint(1,10)):
            Path(f"{output[0]}/{i}").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
            Path(f"{output[0]}/{i}/test.txt").touch()


checkpoint second:
    input:
        'first/{i}/test.txt'
    output:
        directory('second/{i}')
    run:
        for j in range(random.randint(1,10)):
            Path(f"{output[0]}/{j}").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
            Path(f"{output[0]}/{j}/test2.txt").touch()


rule copy:
    input:
        'second/{i}/{j}/test2.txt'
    output:
        'copy/{i}/{j}/test2.txt'
    shell:
        """
        cp -f {input} {output}
        """


def aggregate(wildcards):
    outputs_i = glob.glob(f"{checkpoints.first.get().output}/*/")
    outputs_i = [output.split('/')[-2] for output in outputs_i]
    split_files = []
    for i in outputs_i:
        outputs_j = glob.glob(f"{checkpoints.second.get(i=i).output}/*/")
        outputs_j = [output.split('/')[-2] for output in outputs_j]
        for j in outputs_j:
            split_files.append(f"copy/{i}/{j}/test2.txt")

    return split_files


rule collect:
    input:
        aggregate
    output:
        touch('collect/all_done.txt')
```

Comment: Thanks Maarten. Slight difference to my stated problem: change {wildcards.i} in checkpoint second to {j}. But that doesn't break anything. The solution is to use the outputs (directories) of the second checkpoint as input for the aggregate rule (instead of the produced dynamic files), thereby the second checkpoint is invoked. I will test if it works also if I perform more jobs on the files produced by the second checkpoint, but I think I should be always able to set the wildcards using glob.glob as if I were using just a bash script. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. Just know that wildcards between rules (*generally*) do not hold any relation to each other. So changing i to j shouldn't matter at all, since the wildcard of rule first is not related in any way to the wildcard of rule second.

Comment: But in this case you would overwrite j times the file /second/{i}/{i}/test2.txt, wouldn't you? In my case you create j subdirectories for /second/{i}/ and the number j differs for each i, or am I wrong?

Comment: I think the solution only works if you don't process the files from the second checkpoint further. 
If you have another rule like:
    rule copy:
      input: 'second/{i}/{j}/test2.txt'
      output: 'copy/{i}/{j}/test2.txt'
      shell: 'cp -f {input} {output}'
    
How do you declare /copy/{i}/{j}/test2.txt as target? 
You can't actually get the output of checkpoints.second anymore because the wildcard {i} doesn't exist anymore. It would make sense that one has first to resolve the nested checkpoint (checkpoint.second) and only afterwards checkpoint.first.

Comment: @afh I added rule copy and changed the aggregate function

Comment: Thanks again. I tried something similar but couldn't get the second checkpoint running. If you have additional wildcards, don't forget to include them in both of the _get calls_ in _def aggregate_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202443/discussion-between-maarten-vd-sande-and-afh).